# How to make a link to S3 file download

Tags: python, html, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to make a linke to download S3 stored file.

`<a href="https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.txt" download>DownLoad</a>`
it only display `file.txt` on the browser.
So I found way to download. It is add `Content-Disposition : attachment` meta tag to file.

But I need to add this meta tag to new file automately. So I made `lambda function` by python.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e

    try:
        s3_2 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3_object = s3_2.Object(bucket, key)
        print(s3_object.metadata)
        s3_object.metadata.update({'ContentDisposition':'attachment'})

        print(bucket, key)

        s3_object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket':bucket, 'Key':key}, Metadata=s3_object.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')

    except:
        print(s3_object.metadata)

    return response['ContentType']
```

But this function add `user defined metatag` not `system metatag`. . .

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Disposition` is treated by S3 as (somewhat) more like system metadata than custom/user-defined metadata, so it has its own argument.

```
s3_object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket':bucket, 'Key':key}, ContentDisposition='attachment',  Metadata=s3_object.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

Note that you still need `Metadata` and `MetadataDirective` as shown, for this to work, but `s3_object.metadata.update()` is not required since you are not changing the custom metadata.

Comment: Oh I see! So I changed my lambda function and I works well but, the object url doesn't work.

Comment: There is no problem in lambda function and file uploading, but if link in to object url, it returns 403 access denied. (the bucket is public)